# How to export report and mark a column with data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is hard to explain but I'll try. I need to export a report that shows which stores have locations in which states.

Suppose I have the following table:

```
+----------+-----------+
| STORE_ID | STATE_ABV |
+----------+-----------+
|        1 | AK        |
|        1 | AL        |
|        1 | AR        |
|        2 | MI        |
|        2 | OH        |
|        2 | IN        |
|        3 | CA        |
|        3 | NV        |
+----------+-----------+
```

The `STORE_ID` column is a key to another table where I just need to pull out the `STORE_NAME` column.

```
+----------+------------+
| STORE_ID | STORE_NAME |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Walmart    |
|        2 | Target     |
|        3 | Kroeger's  |
+----------+------------+
```

What I want is to export a list of each store along with columns for all states. If the store is available in that state, I want to place an "X" for the value.

So the desired output looks like this:

```
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| STORE_NAME | AK | AL | AR | CA | IN | OH | MI | NV |
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Walmart    | X  | X  | X  |    |    |    |    |    |
| Target     |    |    |    |    | X  | X  | X  |    |
| Kroeger's  |    |    |    | X  |    |    |    | X  |
+------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Is this possible in SQL Server?  How would I write such a query? There should be a column for every `STATE_ABV` that exists in the table.

Comment: Your looking for a PIVOT (dynamic or not), OR a conditional aggregation.  Either way, you missing the table structure which contains Store_Name

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Thank you, I threw that into the question too.

Comment: I'm looking into the `PIVOT` function now, though. Looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you want the dynamic pivot.   Personally, I don't mind PIVOT.  It is just another screwdriver in the toolbox.

The `UNION ALL` portion can be removed if you don't mind NULL values

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a6efb119107a9e5a53b3bc5b08776b89)**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
From (
      Select A.Store_ID
            ,A.State_Abv
            ,B.Store_Name
            ,Value = ''X''
       From  StoreLocations A
       Join  Stores         B on  A.Store_ID=B.Store_ID
       Union All
       Select B.Store_ID
             ,A.State_Abv
             ,B.Store_Name
            ,Value = ''''
      From  (Select Distinct State_Abv from StoreLocations) A
      Cross Join Stores    B 
     ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [State_Abv] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(State_Abv) From  StoreLocations Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
 Order By Store_ID
'

Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Option with NULL Values**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
From (
      Select A.Store_ID
            ,A.State_Abv
            ,B.Store_Name
            ,Value = ''X''
       From  StoreLocations A
       Join  Stores         B on  A.Store_ID=B.Store_ID
     ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [State_Abv] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(State_Abv) From  StoreLocations Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
 Order By Store_ID
'
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: In my live database, for some reason, I'm getting an error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Walmart' to data type int.`

Comment: @Zephyr Did you get a mixup of Store_ID and Store_Name ?

Comment: You know I did. Thank you; this perfectly solves my question!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, what you are after here is to pivot your data. Personally I dislike the `PIVOT` functionality of SQL Server, and much more prefer using a Cross-Tab (aka conditional aggregation).

As I suspect that this is going to require a dynamic pivot, I've done that as well:

```
--Sample tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.StoreLocations (StoreID int,
                                 StateAbv char(2));
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stores (StoreID int IDENTITY,
                         StoreName varchar(20));
GO
--Sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.Stores (StoreName)
VALUES('Walmart'),('Target'),('Kroeger''s');

INSERT INTO dbo.StoreLocations (StoreID,StateAbv)
VALUES(1,'AK'),
      (1,'AL'),
      (1,'AR'),
      (2,'MI'),
      (2,'OH'),
      (2,'IN'),
      (3,'CA'),
      (3,'NV');
GO
--Quick sample to get the format right
SELECT S.StoreName,
       IIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN SL.StateAbv = 'AK' THEN 1 END) = 0,NULL, 'X') AS AK
FROM dbo.Stores S
     LEFT JOIN dbo.StoreLocations SL ON S.StoreID = SL.StoreID
GROUP BY S.StoreName;
GO
--The real solution
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT S.StoreName,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'       IIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN SL.StateAbv = ' + QUOTENAME(SL.StateAbv,'''') + N' THEN 1 END) = 0, NULL,''X'') AS ' + QUOTENAME(SL.StateAbv)
                  FROM dbo.StoreLocations SL
                  GROUP BY SL.StateAbv --Could use DISTINCT too
                  ORDER BY SL.StateAbv
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM dbo.Stores S' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     LEFT JOIN dbo.StoreLocations SL ON S.StoreID = SL.StoreID' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'GROUP BY S.StoreName;';

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.Stores;
DROP TABLE dbo.StoreLocations;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a61506ecd0288f1e3a519726895070fe)

I *foolishly* assumed that the state was unique in `StoreLocations`. Ideally, you should have a `States` table as well, then you don't need to get the distinct states from the `StoreLocations` table.

Example with a `States` table: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f1877bd9f65b55b648dd45152ea4e63b)

Comment: On my live data, I'm getting an error that the "number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements."  Is there a way to do this without a limit on the size of the table? There are over 77,000 rows in this table.

Comment: That'll be because the sample had only one store per state, so i didn't aggregate up. Fixed, @Zephyr